# In App Purchase not showing up on the Appstore Connect sales/analytics dashboard?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

We have been seeing sales data on our database but we cannot see any sales in the Appstore Connect console. Does anyone have any idea what would cause this situation?

We only complete transaction and give the credits to the user when apple's in app purchase's *.purchased* state callback triggered. But after 7 days passed, we still cannot see any sales data on the Appstore Connect dashboard.

Would that be a trick to fool iOS In App Purchase's for getting free credits?

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            complete(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .failed:
            fail(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
            restore(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .deferred:
            break
        case .purchasing:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing data either for any time frame (7 day, 30 day, etc.). I know I had sales within the last 30days. It seems to have started happening with the start of WWDC.

Comment: But the weird thing is that we tested with one of our friend, he purchased credit, his sales data is showing in the appstore connect sales dashboard. :/ Do you see some or none sales?

Comment: Ok, i just went to 'sales and tends reports' and downloaded some of the .txts. Now things are showing up in 'sales' and 'proceeds'. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the issue. It has been happening because one user has admitted that she has been using **a jail broken iPhone** and that way she was able to **purchase in app purchase items for free**! What a shame Apple! Now we are thinking how we could get our payments and compensate the cost of these fraud sales...